# Отключение клавиатуры при достижении максимального количества символов EditText

Tags: android

Подскажите, как программно можно выполнить, что бы при наборе в EditText максимального количества символов заданного maxLenght клавиатура автоматически убиралась? Спасибо

```
EditText xKNPEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xKNP);
        avtoOffKeyPress(xKNPEditText);
......
public void avtoOffKeyPress(final EditText mEditText)
    {
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.i("MyApp", "Длина= "+mEditText.getText().toString().length());
                if(mEditText.getText().toString().length() == 5){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Почему то не обращается к методу????

Comment: Опишите что именно у вас не получается - как скрыть клавиатуру, как вычислять достигли ли вы предела или как выполнить действие при достижении предела.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `TextWatcher`,  в методе `onTextChanged(),` сравнивайте текущую длину введенного текста в  `edittext` с максимально возможной длиной, как только сравняются, уберайте клавиатуру так

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Примерно так:

```
mEditText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(mEditText.getText().toString().length() == 5){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Если есть необходимость контролирования нескольких `editText`, то можно создать свой `TextWatcher`.

Пример,  **вложенного** класса,  он располагается в классе активности.

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        if( view instanceof EditText){
            EditText editText = (EditText) view;

            if(editText.getText().toString().length() == 5){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
}
```

Использование

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(mEditText));
```

Comment: Спасибо, я ещё новичок. Можно на примере показать как связать объект EditText и TextWatcher. Спасибо.

Comment: Задача такая, есть EditText, maxLenght у которого 5 надо что бы при вводе 5 символов клавиатура убиралась, а текст считывался.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Можно посмотреть код, почему не обращается к методу.

Comment: @Alexandr какому методу? Это весь код,  не считая XML и объявления  editText

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста мой редактированный вопрос. avtoOffKeyPress не вызывается, соответственно клавиатура не отключается.

Comment: @Alexandr а зачем вы этот метод используете? Я не уверен,  что такая конструкция должна работать как надо

Comment: А какой выход? Прописывать Ваш пример для каждой EditText?

Comment: @Alexandr сейчас дополню ответ, с телефона правда

Comment: Не работает, ругается на private и надо как-то изменить сам метод onTextChanged

Comment: В первом случае выдает ошибку Error:(52, 20) error: local variable mEditText is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: Работает у кого-нибудь этот код?

Comment: Только что проверил, код полностью рабочий, обратите внимание, класс `GenericTextWatcher` находиться внутри вашего класса `Activity`, а не в отдельном файле, поэтому никаких изменений не требуется.

Comment: Что то у меня не работает, все сделал как описано, ошибок нет, в классе перед условием Log поставил, до него исполнение кода не доходит.

Comment: Спасибо, код работает, ошибка была у меня в программе.